# How to use LOCK IN SHARE MODE with hibernate/spring?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, jpa

I'm running into a deadlock scenario when using MySQL and Hibernate (with Spring). I'm getting the following exception message:

> could not get or update next value;
>   SQL[null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException
>   ...Deadlock found when trying to get
>   lock; try restarting transaction

My MySQL db has its transaction isolation level configured to READ COMMITTED, and I did some looking into the INNODB status to see what was happening when the deadlock occurred. Essentially I see two transactions where one is trying to select a row from a table while the other is trying to update that row. The table in contention here is my "unique id" table. I have a common, root object which other @Entity objects extend. This root object defines the "id" property and is annotated with @Id, @TableGenerator and @GeneratedValue.

Some digging around led me to believe that setting the LockMode to UPGRADE for the "select" on that table might help and/or changing the "select" so that instead of it using "select .... **for update**" it would use "select .... **lock in share mode**".

Any ideas if setting the Lockmode.upgrade would really help or changing "for update" to "lock in share mode"? Secondly, how would I do this with spring + hibernate...I was leaning towards implementing a custom LoadEventListener (which would extend the DefaultLoadEventListener).

Comment: I saw this ticket http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HB-398 ..which indicates that the LOCK IN SHARE MODE will not be directly supported by hibernate but it seems like a custom "select" could be used.

Answer (score 0):

The particular case I ran into was the deadlocks were occurring my "id generator" table. Ultimately I found that my app was using the org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator which builds up the select statement (internally that class stores it in the "query" property) and adds the "for update" string (which it actually gets from the org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect class (getForUpdateString method).

The solution for this particular instance was to have the Id generator use "lock in share mode" instead of "for update" when performing the "select" from my Id table. Using a custom dialect (i.e. override the getForUpdateString method wasn't viable b/c I didn't want 'lock in share mode' all the time, just in this case).

Therefore I had to create my own Id generator class. I do wish the MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator was a bit easier to extend (i.e. wish I could have just overridden a 'createSelectSql' method).